# Recursive function return empty list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

```
function getLineItemList(quotationItemElements, checkedLineItemIds) {
var lineItemList = [];
quotationItemElements.children.forEach(function (quotElement, index) {
    if(!parseBoolean(quotElement.isGroup)){
        checkedLineItemIds.forEach(function (checkedId, index) {
            if(quotElement.id == checkedId){
                lineItemList.push(quotElement);
            }
        });
    }else {
        if(quotElement.children.length > 0){
            getLineItemList(quotElement, checkedLineItemIds);
        }
    }
});
return lineItemList;
}
function parseBoolean(str) {
  return /true/i.test(str);
}
```

I have same hierarchy of data at different levels of `JavaScript` list, Instead of looping any level explicitly i am using recursive call (Which is fortunately working fine) But function returns empty list always.

[JSON Data](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=df202eecff96978f4c1af4823e1e6f87)

Comment: Provide a data input example for the above function

Comment: make a jsfiddle so that we can see your code running.

Comment: You define `lineItemList` inside the function which means that you start off with an empty array every time you call the function. You will need to pass the array to the function as a parameter and you also need to `return` the result of the `getLineItemList` function.

Comment: You call `getLineItemList` in you function but you do not use the return value of it.

Comment: @dev please pay look edit

Comment: Has any of this been declared yet? `if(!parseBoolean(quotElement.isGroup)){`

Comment: Debug your program, by stepping through it in the debugger, setting breakpoints and examining variables.

Comment: @dev `parseBoolean()` is Java

Comment: @Usman—don't post additional content as a comment, edit the question. The *parseBoolean* function body could be `return !/0|no|false/i.test(value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `lineItemList` inside the function which means that you start off with an empty array every time you call the function. You will need to pass the array to the function as a parameter and you also need to `return` the result of the `getLineItemList` function.

Try this:

```
function getLineItemList(quotationItemElements, checkedLineItemIds, lineItemList) {
    var lineItemList = lineItemList || [];
    quotationItemElements.children.forEach(function (quotElement, index) {
        if(!parseBoolean(quotElement.isGroup)){
            checkedLineItemIds.forEach(function (checkedId, index) {
                if(quotElement.id == checkedId){
                    lineItemList.push(quotElement);
                }
            });
        }else {
            if(quotElement.children.length > 0){
                return getLineItemList(quotElement, checkedLineItemIds, lineItemList);
            }
        }
    });
    return lineItemList;
}
```

Comment: Basically I forgot to retain the result of recursive call.

Comment: @Usman Yes, you were getting the `lineItemList` array from the first function call.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't capture the return value of the recursive call:

```
    if(quotElement.children.length > 0){
      /* nobody capture this */  getLineItemList(quotElement, checkedLineItemIds);
    }
```

which you should and concat with `lineItemList`. Hence, `lineItemList` stays the way it's declared, which is an empty array. Maybe not if at least one of `quotElement.isGroup` returns true, but without any sample input, we have no idea.

Comment: Sample input is given in post